# Is there a way to specify a first element *type*?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to know is there any way to get the following example of CSS to work as I intend it to?

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.col p:first-child {
   background:yellow;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="col">
    <h1>Woot</h1>
    <p>I am a super nun. I am a super nun.</p>
    <p>I am a super nun. I am a super nun.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically I need the first `<p>` of an element to be styled a certain way... but `first-child` doesn't work if it's the second child (duh), even if I attempt to say: "the first `<p>` element in a parent (i.e. `.col p:first-child`)".

Is it possible to select not the first-child, but the first-child of a *specific type* in CSS?

Comment: Why not use the general sibling selector as "div.col~p"

Comment: @JAA149: Because that picks up more than one `p`.

Comment: Than we can use the adjacent sibling selector as "h1+p". http://jsfiddle.net/V8LvC/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fortunately, for element **types**, CSS3 supplies the `:first-of-type` pseudo-class (there is no first of class, first of pseudo-class, first with a certain attribute, etc).

```
.col > p:first-of-type
```

Unfortunately, since it's a CSS3 selector, browser support for it is pretty poor. Of all IE versions, only IE9 supports it.

If the structure of `.col` is predictable (enough) in that, for example, it always contains one element followed by a `p`, you could do something like this instead, with just CSS2 selectors:

```
.col > :first-child + p
```

Comment: Awesome! Great to hear. Now I just need to see how well it's supported.

Comment: That's just going to depress you.

Comment: Oh, that's great. I had no idea CSS2 selectors were so useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That would be the [`:first-of-type`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/CR-css3-selectors-20011113/#first-of-type-pseudo) pseudo-class.

> The `:first-of-type` pseudo-class represents an element that is the first sibling of its type in the list of children of its parent element.

---

> Now I just need to see how well it's supported.

[Here's](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t34) the quirksmode compatibility table you're looking for. The short version: forget about IE <9.

Comment: Thanks, Matt. That's very useful. Given the structure is very predictable in my case, I can happily use CSS2 selectors. I had no idea that was even possible.